# multiple docker exec commands break

Tags: docker

I want to run multiple docker commands in cmd with pasting. But only the first command executed, others were ignored.

```
docker exec -it my-container grep A .
docker exec -it my-container grep B .
docker exec -it my-container grep C .
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell you are using probably does not recognize the line endings you originally pasted with.

Try copy pasting this

```
docker exec -it my-container grep A .
docker exec -it my-container grep B .
docker exec -it my-container grep C .
```

If that does not work then try with semicolons

```
docker exec -it my-container grep A .;
docker exec -it my-container grep B .;
docker exec -it my-container grep C .;
```

Which terminal are you using on which operating system?